# Facebook Timeline Aggregations Filters not working

Tags: facebook-timeline

I'm creating aggregations and setting a filter in the advanced section.

```
eg: x.category == Style
where x is an object defined in the open graph section of my app and catgory is a custom variable defined for that object
```

These aggregations don't seem to work. I'm definitely passing the category variable to facebook via the og tags. I can validate that because I use {x.category} in the caption field and it shows the right category. I've changed the aggregation to show actions and objects and neither seem to work. The aggregation box would just not show at all.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't help with this, other than to confirm it's also happening for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We reached out to the Facebook team and apparently this is a critical bug and they're working on a fix.